# HTML/CSS/JS/jQuery Need a tooltip by keydown for a grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltip

everyone. I'm working on a project that has a list of images. The user can scroll over the images and then press "enter" to bring up tooltip that tells them more about their selection.

I've been looking into tooltips, but they seem to be more geared towards using a mouse and I cannot get modified CSS tooltip code to place the information over the image when selected.

So, what I'm hoping is that someone can direct me to a method that can work with popping up a bubble of information using keystrokes.

```
function loatTooltip()
{
    $('.tooltip').remove(); 
    var name=contentName[navPosition][position.x]; 
    if(position.y>0) 
        name=contentName[navPosition][position.x+4]; 
    contentList[position.y][position.x].after('<div title="'+name+'" class="tooltip"></div>');
}

.tooltip { 
          display:block; 
          position: absolute; 
          width: 250px; 
          height: 120px; 
          background: #000000; 
          -webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
          -moz-border-radius: 10px; 
          border-radius: 10px; 
          left:5%; 
} 
.tooltip:after { 
          display:block; 
          content: attr(title); 
          position: absolute; 
          display: block; 
          width: 95%; 
          z-index: 99; 
          color:white; 
} 
content: attr(title);
```

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what you mean when you say "The user can scroll over the images and then press "enter" to bring up tooltip". How does the user "scroll over" the images? Is this using keyboard keys or using the mouse?

Comment: @user3504898 If possible, post `html`, `css` `js`, text for "tooltip". Thanks

Comment: I have a 2D array that handles as a matrix for a grid of images. When the user presses the directional keys, my code moves a selection window over a new image. While this image is selected, the user can press enter and a tooltip/dialogue bubble appears and gives information about the image. Right now, I can get a tooltip to appear, but it always appear in the same place, meaning that it won't hover over the selected image.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this a "first draft" - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7qsbu/).

Image in a div, hover and an absolutely positioned div pops up with the text inside it.

I've done "hover" and not "active" (selected) because of ease. But you can probably take the concept and move it to an "active" div or put a border around it, and "if border" change the CSS.

JS

```
$('.holder').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).children('div').css({ 'display': 'block',
                                 'background-color': 'red'});
    },
    function(){
        $(this).children('div').css('display', 'none');
    }
    );
```

Comment: This looks like what I have already initialized. Using your example, I added a second image to the list. The .hover event triggers when I move my cursor over each image, but the tooltip appears in the same location. What do I need to do to make it appear over the image that the cursor is hovering on?

Comment: The key is the $(this), meaning what you are hovering over. Then you associate a hidden div with each of the images, and when hover, display the div as a block. Position it relative to the hovered div.

Comment: Here is an updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/7qsbu/1/ - with three images, all the same, but different descriptions. You can change the position of the popup relative to the image in the CSS.

Comment: That's working just like I would hope! The last trick is making this so that the popups appear when the user selects the image with keystrokes and not mouse-overs. This is the function that I'm using right now for when the enter button is pressed. Now, this syncs up when I use this to draw a border around the image. But it won't center on the image when I try to draw my tooltip class over the same selected image.

Comment: How about if you edit your question and put the HTML and CSS in it?